# Waiting without Sleeping?

Tags: c#, function, wait

What I'm trying to do is start a function, then change a bool to false, wait a second and turn it to true again. However I'd like to do it without the function having to wait, how do I do this?

I can only use Visual C# 2010 Express.

This is the problematic code. I am trying receive user input (right arrow for example) and move accordingly, but not allow further input while the character is moving.

```
        x = Test.Location.X;
        y = Test.Location.Y;
        if (direction == "right") 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            {
                x++;
                Test.Location = new Point(x, y);
                Thread.Sleep(31);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int xmax = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 32;
        int ymax = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - 32;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && x < xmax) direction = "right";
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && x > 0) direction = "left";
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && y > 0) direction = "up";
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down && y < ymax) direction = "down";

        if (moveAllowed)
        {
            moveAllowed = false;
            Movement();
        }
        moveAllowed = true;  
    }
```

Comment: What do you consider the difference between waiting and sleeping?  Do you want other code to run in the meantime?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, i do want to run other code at the same time.

Comment: @BrianTompsett Please do not resurrect old questions to make trivial edits. Fix *everything* at once. The "edit" markers do not belong, the "I have solved this" does not belong in the question (the accepted answer indicates that), and the wording had a lot of room for tightening up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith((t) => Console.WriteLine("I'm done"));
```

or

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
Console.WriteLine("I'm done");
```

---

For the older frameworks you can use the following:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
timer.Elapsed += delegate { Console.WriteLine("I'm done"); };
timer.AutoReset = false;
timer.Start();
```

Example according to the description in the question:

```
class SimpleClass
{
    public bool Flag { get; set; }

    public void function()
    {
        Flag = false;
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += (src, args) => { Flag = true; Console.WriteLine("I'm done"); };
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Delay' C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\meh\meh\Form1.cs 57 22 meh

Comment: @UltimateAlloy: Try using a more recent version of .NET. `Task.Delay` was introduced in .NET 4.5. Also, if you use C# 5, you can use `async`/`await`...

Comment: The issue is that I'm required to use Visual C# 2010 Express for this task, so I can't sadly.

Comment: Edited, got any other ideas?

Comment: Alright, so how do I run the (timer with changing variable) and (function) separate from each other?

Comment: @UltimateAlloy, I've added an example. I hope it reflects your need

Comment: @ixSci Since I am partly not the most intelligent person, and am having trouble understanding within my context, I have attached some code above to give further context, sorry for my lack of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I realize an answer has already been accepted, and I do like `ixSci`'s answer where he recommends the use of a `Timer` object to accomplish OP's goal.

However, using `System.Timers.Timer` specifically introduces threading considerations. And to ensure correctness in this case, more code is required to properly synchronize the boolean flag value.  Basically, anywhere where the flag is read or written, the code region would need to have a lock statement defined around it.

It would have to look something like this:

```
private final object flagLock = new object();
private bool moveAllowed = true;
private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

public Form1()
{
    this.timer.Interval = 1000;
    this.timer.AutoReset = false;
    this.timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
    {
        // this DOES NOT run on the UI thread, so locking IS necessary to ensure correct behavior.
        this.timer.Stop();
        lock (this.flagLock) {
            this.moveAllowed = true;
        }
    };
}

// The code in this event handler runs on the UI thread.
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Locking is necessary here too.
    lock (this.flagLock) {
        if (this.moveAllowed)
        {
            this.moveAllowed = false;
            Movement();
            this.timer.Start(); // wait 1 second to reset this.moveAllowed to true.
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, to avoid having to think about threads, perhaps OP could consider using a different flavor of the `Timer` class. Namely: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. This way, the boolean flag will always be read/written on the UI thread, and no extra locking of any sort is required to ensure correctness.

In this case, the code would look something like this:

```
private bool moveAllowed = true;
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

public Form1()
{
    this.timer.Interval = 1000;
    this.timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        // this runs on the UI thread, so no locking necessary.
        this.timer.Stop(); // this call is necessary, because unlike System.Timers.Timer, there is no AutoReset property to do it automatically.
        this.moveAllowed = true;
    };
}

// The code in this event handler runs on the UI thread.
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.moveAllowed)
    {
        this.moveAllowed = false;
        Movement();
        this.timer.Start(); // wait 1 second to reset this.moveAllowed to true.
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, do i have to change anything else other than the name of the class? Like the values etc? Could you send me some example code?

Comment: @UltimateAlloy: I edited my answer to provide sample code of both options.